# How to get iOS Crash Logs of a Adhoc Distribution for a Enterprise Account

Tags: iphone, itunes, app-store-connect, enterprise

I have just release the distribution of an App using an adhoc distribution with an Apple Enterprise Account. Everything was fine so  my exclusive number of ten users are enjoying the App.

My question now is, providing that while using Enterprise Account there is no need to use Itunes Connect, how could I get the crash logs  when they eventually appear?

As far as I know Itunes Connect is the only way to get this crash logs.

Comment: Have you considered a solution like Crashlytics? https://www.crashlytics.com.

Comment: iTunes Connect is worthless for crash logs IMO, they don't report all occurrences, only ones that happen frequently. It is also dependent on the user allowing them to be reported. Stick with Crashlytics, HockeyApp, or Crittercism.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com) to deal with getting crash reports. You could also use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) to get them, and TestFlight would also make it easier to distribute new builds to your users.